# SQL Insert, Update Trigger - Can you update the inserted table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, insert

I have an SQL Trigger FOR INSERT, UPDATE I created which basically does the following:

Gets a LineID (PrimaryID for the table) and RegionID From the Inserted table and stores this in INT variables.
It then does a check on joining tables to find what the RegionID should be and if the RegionID is not equal what it should be from the Inserted table, then it should update that record.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TestTrigger]
ON [dbo].[PurchaseOrderLine]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS

-- Find RegionID and PurchaseOrderLineID
DECLARE @RegionID AS INT
DECLARE @PurchaseOrderLineID AS INT
SELECT @RegionID = RegionID, @PurchaseOrderLineID = PurchaseOrderLineID FROM Inserted

-- Find PurchaserRegionID (if any) for the Inserted Line
DECLARE @PurchaserRegionID AS INT
SELECT @PurchaserRegionID = PurchaserRegionID
FROM 
(...
    ) UpdateRegionTable 
WHERE UpdateRegionTable.PurchaseOrderLineID = @PurchaseOrderLineID

-- Check to see if the PurchaserRegionID has a value
IF @PurchaserRegionID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
-- If PurchaserRegionID has a value, compare it with the current RegionID of the Inserted PurchaseOrderLine, and if not equal then update it
IF @PurchaserRegionID <> @RegionID
BEGIN
    UPDATE PurchaseOrderLine
    SET RegionID = @PurchaserRegionID
    WHERE PurchaseOrderLineID = @PurchaseOrderLineID
END 
END
```

The problem I have is that it is not updating the record and I'm guessing, it is because the record hasn't been inserted yet into the PurchaseOrderLine table and I'm doing an update on that. But can you update the row which will be inserted from the Inserted table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved. I resolved the problem by adding the trigger to another table as the IF @PurchaserRegionID IS NOT NULL was always false.

Comment: HI all I have a same issue some one can help me,See the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26043106/how-to-determine-if-insert-or-update/26043654?noredirect=1#comment40803473_26043654

Answer (score 1):

The major problem with your trigger is that it's written in assumption that you always get only one row in `INSERTED` virtual table.

SQL Server triggers are statement-triggers not row-triggers. You have to take that fact into consideration.

Now if I understand correctly the logic behind this trigger then you need just one update statement in it

```
CREATE TRIGGER TestTrigger ON PurchaseOrderLine
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
  UPDATE l
     SET RegionID = u.PurchaserRegionID
    FROM PurchaseOrderLine l JOIN INSERTED i
      ON l.PurchaseOrderLineID = i.PurchaseOrderLineID JOIN 
         (
           SELECT PurchaseOrderLineID, PurchaserRegionID 
             FROM UpdateRegionTable  -- !!! change this for your proper subquery
         ) u ON l.PurchaseOrderLineID = u.PurchaseOrderLineID
```

*For this example I've created a fake table `UpdateRegionTable`. You have to change it to the proper query that returns `PurchaseOrderLineID, PurchaserRegionID` (in your code you replaced it with `...`). Make sure that it returns all necessary rows, not **one**.*

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8891a/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was working on the problem and figured out a flaw in my logic which resulted in the conditional IF @PurchaserRegionID IS NOT NULL to always be false. I wasn't aware of the inserted table returns rows and not just one row :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be that you are making the update to `PurchaceOrderLine` inside the trigger that is monitoring updates to the same table as well. Try to alter the trigger to just monitor the inserts, than if this works, you can make some changes or break your trigger on two: one for inserts, another for updates.